# Android Studio error: class, interface, enum expected

Tags: java, android

Starting with line 34 I am getting error: class, interface, enum expected. This is a simple percent calculator app as my introduction to android studio. I have tried fix all all the formatting suggestion I read for other people getting the same error but I had no luck. I would appreciate any suggestions or ideas on how to fix that or also if you have any basic app ideas I would love to hear them.

```
package com.example.bheue.percenttutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    TextView totalTextView;
    EditText percentageText;
    EditText numberText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            }
        };


            TextView totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalText);
            percentageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentageText);
            numberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberText);
            Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
            calcButton.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener())
           @Override
           public void onClick(view view){
               float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageText.getText().toString());
               float dec = percentage / 100;
               float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberText.getText().toString());
               totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

Comment: Its because you have all these extra braces just lying around in your code

Comment: And in a lot of places where you should have `View` class, you have `view` object

Comment: I fixed the brackets but noe it is giving me a <identifier> expected error

Comment: Can you update your code so I can check?

Answer (score -1):

This is what your code should be:

```
package com.example.bheue.percenttutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.uplication.hamza.helpinghands.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  TextView totalTextView;
  EditText percentageText;
  EditText numberText;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final TextView totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalText);
    percentageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentageText);
    numberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberText);
    Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageText.getText().toString());
        float dec = percentage / 100;
        float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberText.getText().toString());
        totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Did you copy this code from somewhere and had problems in pasting?